# How to read the data of a SD card configured as "Internal Storage"

Tags: factory-reset, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I have made a factory reset in my moto g2(Android 6.0) after removing the SD card which was configured as Internal storage. After the reset, my phone is unable to detect the SD card and asks to format it for either use it as an Portable or Internal storage.
The SD card is failed to be detected by any card reader/other devices.
How to access the data's in the SD card?

Comment: As acejavelin wrote, the answer is "you cannot". For details, please see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info).

Answer (score 4):

You don't... if the SD card was encrypted adopted storage, and you removed it and factory reset the phone then you have lost all possibility of accessing any information on the SD card. You are better off just to reformat the card and start over.

The encryption "key" was stored on the device, but when you factory reset it the encryption key was deleted, it was a random key and cannot be regenerated. You have lost all possibility of accessing this card.

If the card was portable storage, then put it in a PC and try to read it, if it still won't read the card is probably bad or corrupted and should be formatted or replaced.